# Way to separate files from folders in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I've recently switched from Windows to OSX and I'm looking for a proper IDE. I was using PHPDesigner on windows and now I'm trying Eclipse on OSX.

So in PHPDesigner and some other IDEs I've used over the years, there was a way to split the file tree into distinct folders and files. At the top would be the file tree like normal, and below it was another box that contained just the files in the selected folder. This is good for me as alot of the projects I've been working on have more then a few files in each folder.

Eclipse simply has the tree view, and when you click on a folder it lists all the sub-directories and files, quickly cluttering the tree and making it harder to navigate to different directories.

Is there a way to make Eclipse split the directory/files from its tree browser? Any other IDE suggestions for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to"un-cluttering" the tree of files/directories, you can use **[mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)** (which is already part of Eclipse: you don't have to install it).

See [this tutorial](http://tasktop.com/mylyn/mylyn-2.0-part2.php): mylyn has a task-focused display approach which will let you display only what you are working on.

[image: task focused workspace]

> Mylyn's focusing facilities can be applied to all the views that show context in the Eclipse SDK: Package Explorer, Navigator, Project Explorer, Outline, Problems, Tasks, Debug, Packages, Types, and Members.
>   The focused mode of any tree view, such as the Project Explorer, adds interest decoration, filtering, and expansion management. List views, such as Problems, are also sorted by interest when focused.
>   **Thanks to this generic support, you can use Mylyn for non-Java projects, such as PHP development**.